# What is the difference between a 120v 10 amp transformer and a 240v 5 amp transformer?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, maximum-ratings

I can't seem to find an answer for this online. What are the design considerations taken into account to determine the voltage rating of a transformer? If a transformer made in the U.S. is rated for 120v and intended to draw 10 amps, and its U.K. equivalent is rated for 240v and intended to draw 5 amps, what exactly is the difference between the two? What would happen if you connected a U.S. transformer directly to a U.K. outlet with its secondary open?

Comment: Both have the same kVA rating, but the 5A one would have twice the windings.  UK transformer could plug into NA power, but not the other way around.

Comment: The UK one would have double the turns on the primary. Most likely the additional voltage would saturate the US one's core , reducing the primary inductance to a very low value, allowing immense off-load current, along with all the downsides that accompany immense current.

Comment: A lot. For example the voltage and current are not the only factors, usually the mains frequency is also different which has to be taken into the calculations.

Comment: Both allow you to draw the same amount of power from the supply. But the key parameter you have not mentioned is the output voltage. Two transformers cannot really be compared without knowing this. For example if you connect a US transformer to a UK supply it will either melt its insulation or deliver twice the rated output voltage.

Comment: In some cases, just how the windings are connected. Two 120 V 5 A windings in series give you 240 V 5 A, and in parallel, 120 V 10 A. This is used in a lot of devices (particularly ones from the 00s and earlier) to provide a switchable input voltage--remember those big red slide switches on the back of computer PSUs?

Answer (score 3):

The two main factors influencing the voltage and current rating of a transformer are:

1. Voltage: This is determined by the winding insulation.  A 240V winding needs to withstand twice the voltage potential of a 120V winding.
2. Current: This is determined by the wire size or gauge.  A 10A winding needs to be able to handle twice the current of a 5A winding.

There are other factors such as the turns ratio, core material and saturation characteristics, etc.

If you connected a 120V rated transformer to 240V you may or may not have problems such a insulation breakdown, shorts, smoke, and burning.  It just depends on the safety margin.  But it's generally a BAD idea to exceed the stated limits.

Answer (score 1):

General Transformer Equation:

$$V_{RMS} = 4.44 f N \phi_M$$

\$\phi_M\$ is maximum flux of iron core.  Let's say we have 1000 turns.

An European transformer would have a maximum flux of:

$$\phi_M = \frac {V_{RMS}} {4.44 f N} = \frac {240V} {4.44 \times 50Hz \times 1000 turns} = 1.08 mWb $$

We take it to NA.  Flux produced is:

$$\phi = \frac {V_{RMS}} {4.44 f N} = \frac {120V} {4.44 \times 60Hz \times 1000 turns} = 450 \mu Wb$$

A 240V, 5A transformer rated at 1.2kVA would only be able to produce 41.7% of the apparent power at 120V (500VA).

If we take a NA transformer of 1000 turns, it's \$\phi_M\$ would be \$450 \mu Wb\$.

If we take it to Europe, the 240V and 50Hz would produce too much flux (1.08 mWb), but the iron will saturate at \$450 \mu Wb\$.

This should produce excess heat from higher voltage and heavy distortion on the secondary voltage.